# Python inner class inherit from outer

Tags: python, oop

I have an issue with class inheritence and haven't been able to find an appropriate solution elsewhere.

I have 2 classes a `Parent` class and a `Child` class.

A `Child` is a type of `Human` so I want to use class inheritance, which normally would be straightforward we just have.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self,type,name):     # Do this when we create a Node instance
        self.type = type
        self.name = name

class Child(Human):
    def __init__(self,name,siblings):     # Do this when we create a Node instance
        super().__init__(type=Child,name=name)
        self.siblings = siblings
```

but I want to be a pain and I want to create instances by using `Human.Child(parameters)` rather than `Child(parameters)` and I don't want to have a `Child` class in the main scope.

I have managed to make that work by using a classmethod but it's pretty messy. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self,type,name):     # Do this when we create a Node instance
        self.type = type
        self.name = name

    def execute(self):
        print(f"executing the Human {self.name}")


    @classmethod
    def Child(cls,*args,**kwargs):

        class Child(cls):
            def __init__(self,name,siblings):
                super().__init__(type=Child,name=name)
                self.siblings = siblings

            def execute(self):
                print(f"executing the Child {self.name}")

        return(Child(*args,**kwargs))
```

ideally it would look something like below, but of course, we cannot pass `Human` to the `Child` class as it hasn't yet been defined.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self,type,name):     # Do this when we create a Node instance
        self.type = type
        self.name = name

    def execute(self):
        print(f"executing the Human {self.name}")


    class Child(Human):
        def __init__(self,name,siblings):
            super().__init__(type=Child,name=name)
            self.siblings = siblings

        def execute(self):
            print(f"executing the Child {self.name}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a class definition is encountered, the class object isn't created until the entire body is read, and a full dictionary accumulated. This is the opposite of how a module object is created, where an empty module is available immediately to help avoid circular imports, among other things. That being said, nothing prevents you from modifying the attributes of a class after it is fully created.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self,type,name):     # Do this when we create a Node instance
        self.type = type
        self.name = name

class Child(Human):
    def __init__(self,name,siblings):     # Do this when we create a Node instance
        super().__init__(type=Child,name=name)
        self.siblings = siblings

Human.Child = Child
del Child
```

A few things to keep in mind:

1. Passing in type is redundant. You can always access that information through the `type` function.
2. Humans tend to have siblings even after they stop being children.
3. While I'm the one suggesting this approach, I do not endorse it. Rather than complicating things without any need, try to keep your classes in the top level namespace.

Comment: Oh that's nice, thank you. Where we pass `type=Child`, that no longer exists so I updated to use `type=Human.Child`  is there a way to access the class of the instance without hardcoding the name? (like cls in a classmethod).  Also it is still technically in the __main__ namespace, is there a way to alter that?

Comment: Just seen your 3. update: what is the reasoning for trying to keep them in the top level namespace?

Comment: @CharlieMorton nested classes are completely isolated from any class namespace that intervenes between them and global. This makes nesting pointless extra work at best, and a source of confusion (read maintenance burden) at worst.